# Searching Pixel Location (idrisi) on Another GIS

Tags: raster

I'm Searching similar command Pixel Location (like idrisi) on Another GIS, I, need create raster file  with values ​​lat, long by separately...

---

Update:

I need a raster file where the value of each cell are Latitude and another raster Longitude, (similar centroid of feature point) but on raster.. So this command on IDRISI Pixel location copy rows & col similar raster e.g srtmdem, and create 2 raster with a distribution for each pixel Latitude an Longitude.

Comment: Please add more context to your question. I don't understand what you are looking for. Remember that many users here will not know Idrisi's Pixel Location command. So explain what it does.

Comment: Hi Underdark.... My problem is I need a raster file where the value of each cell are Latitude and another raster Longitude, (similar centroid of feature point) but on raster.. So this command on IDRISI Pixel location copy rows & col similar raster e.g srtmdem, and create 2 raster with a distribution for each pixel Latitude an Longitude....... For me IDRISI is a pay software GDAL & QGIS is OK

Comment: you need a raster or you need to access that kind of information??

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool in [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html), which is called **Geographic coordinate grids**.

It is found in `Tools > Projection > Proj.4`.

When you activate the tool and provide it with your (geographical) raster layer, it will automatically output two rasters (*Longitude* and *Latitude*). Each output cell has its longitude (or latitude) value of the cell center.

This tool is also available in QGIS, in `Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Projections and Transformations`.

[image]